# If you are near radioactive waves but they don't pass through your body can you still get cancer?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, biophysics, radioactivity, medical-physics

If intense gamma rays are flying in the opposite direction from me will they still affect me?
I wouldn't think they could, yet people can get cancer from being near radioactive materials. Is it because the waves are entering the body?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: Where would this best be suited? Chemistry

Comment: @JohnRennie it is health physics  but it does not exist in SE,  so an active health physics community would fall under the physics.se , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_physics

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. Why do you think people who are *near* radioactive materials are not being hit by gamma rays? Why do you think the gamma rays are *flying in the opposite direction*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Radioactive diseases come from several different processes, all of which require, that the highly energetic radiation is absorbed by biological tissue. Basically the radiation damages the cells in such a way, that they cease to function correctly, which can, for example, result in cancer.

So if radiation from radioactive processes does not enter your body, it does not damage you and you do not get radiation poisoning. But it still is dangerous to be close to a moderately to highly radioactive material. Why? Well, the radiation the material emits, does not just go in a straight line. It goes in every direction equally (not considering some specially prepared systems), so you are not safe no matter where you stand around it.

That said, radiation safety is a complex topic, one should take some time to study, before doing any research with such materials. Better safe than sorry!

Comment: So if the material is hit with high frequency waves, and its absorbed in that material, when other photons hit the atom and raise it to a higher energy state, and if emits a photon to go back to ground the photon it emit will also be high frequency aka radioactive? Is this why material can still be radioactive after years? Sorry if its unrelated.

Comment: If an atom absorbs radiation of a certain frequency, it can also emit it at this frequency. But it the electron can also fall to a lower excited state and thus emit radiation of a lower frequency. There are also some other similar processes, but this is not something specific to radioactive materials. The half-life is also not affected by these processes (as far as I know) and why some atoms are radioactive for a long time, is a different question. You should first see what you can find about it and if there is any confusion, you can post a separate question on this site.